# drop base de datos sin necesidad de entrar a ella

Tags: mysql, bash, script, centos7

quiero dropear una base de datos sin necesidad de entrar a ella:

sudo mysql -u Admin --password=admin123 pollux

quisiera que en esa misma linea de código pudiera dropear la base

Comment: y  ya investigaste como se dropea una base de datos??? desde el CMD???

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suponiendo que tu base de datos (la que quieres dropear) se llame pollux, el comando sería el siguiente:

```
 sudo mysql -u Admin -padmin123 -D pollux -e "DROP DATABASE pollux"
```

Es el mismo comando que tienes tú, solo que añadí la opción **-D** para especificar la base de datos (aunque no es necesario, puedes omitirla y seguiría funcionando), y la opción **-e**, para especificar la consulta que quieres hacer.

Comment: Aconsejo no dejar espacio entre el -p y la contraseña: -padmin123

Comment: @JoséCarlosPHP Genial, lo edito! Gracias